# Filling up the VIDEX Form (Schengen Visa) Regarding Address

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, philippines

My address contains a block number and a lot number, usually written as Block ## Lot ##. This was not accepted in the online application form (VIDEX) of the German Embassy. Their format is also very different. What do I do? :(

[image: it looks like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically fill it out as best as you can in such a way that all data is present and do not be too concerned on how it is split up. For example, the [Dubai instructions](http://de.vfsglobal.ae/pdf/VIDEX_General_User_Guidelines_190613.pdf) list a "Villa 21" as House number -- clearly it can be something else than just a number.

This is just an implementation detail and insignificant at that. There's no legal requirement for a Schengen visa to provide a detailed address. For example, this [French form](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/IMG/pdf/visagb.pdf) for the Schengen visas has a field for the home address and that's it.